# PHP echo, outputting full html code (undesired) before object (desired)

Tags: javascript, php

When I echo $jsonstring, seemingly a whole blank html page is sent over (from PHP to Javascript) with the object I requested.  Super new all around here, so I don't get why.

my php code:

```
<?php

//ini_set('display_errors', '1');
//ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

require "localdbcxn.php";

$encoded = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($encoded, true);

$email = $decoded['email'];
$password = $decoded['password'];
$identify = mysql_query("SELECT UserId FROM users WHERE UserEmail='$email' AND UserPassword='$password'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($identify);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($identify);
$userid = $row['UserId'];

$sessionid = mt_rand(1111111111111111,9999999999999999);
$sessionkey = mt_rand(1111111111111111,9999999999999999);
$logindate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


$login = "INSERT INTO mobileSession (UserId, SessionId, SessionKey, BeginDate) VALUES('$userid','$sessionid','$sessionkey','$logindate') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  SessionId='$sessionid', SessionKey='$sessionkey', BeginDate='$logindate' ";

if ($numrows == 1) {
  mysql_query($login);
  $session = array('UserId'=>$userid,'SessionId'=>$sessionid);
  $jsonstring = json_encode($session);
  echo $jsonstring;
}
?>
```

Here's what the console(log) shows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>{"UserId":"33","SessionId":8207219793564744}
```

From UserID til ...4744 is correct, but can anyone help me understand why the html code is being echoed?  In my limited experience, I haven't seen this before, and feel that I am doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must specify the content type before printing json data. before echo set header -

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but I'm still getting the same result.  Could there be a particular way I should be receiving it in javascript?

Comment: Yes... you can use $.getJSON if familiar with jquery or you can also use simple ajax call setting the content type application/json here also :)